# Как реализуется стандартная библиотека Си/C++?

Tags: stl, c, c++

Добрый день! Хотелось бы узнать (чисто для саморазвития), как реализуется стандартная библиотека в Си/C++? С помощью runtime-библиотек (DLL), или при компоновке компоновщик смотрит неопределенные имена и просто компонует с нужной статической библиотекой? Заранее благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаблоны, естественно, реализованы в виде хедеров. В остальном по-разному. Насколько помню, в VS можно компоновать стандартную библиотеку как динамически, так и статически.

Comment: Нет, ну, на сколько я понимаю, хедеры нужны только для проверки правильности переданных параметров в функции и подобных вещей. Самого кода там нет. Спасибо за ответ! А она компонуется вся полностью, или непосредственно неопределенные имена? Что такое шаблоны еще не знаю, т.к. только начал изучать Си, до C++ еще далеко.

Comment: Самый распространенный и универсальный способ создания библиотек шаблонов С++ - запихивание их в хедеры. Почитайте литературу. Ведь машинный код создается только при инстанциировании шаблона! 

Кроме того, в Си некоторые стандартные функции иногда реализуются в виде макросов, например, gets(). Они тоже запихиваются в хедеры.

Comment: @Azat Galiev, что ж вы все в одну кучу мешаете? В итоге получается полная дребедень =) Хидеры нужны лишь для определения классов, функций и т.д. Они являются носителями определений, если можно так выразиться. Функционал всех описаний реализуют .c, .cpp файлы...

Comment: @SingleAsen Ну это я и так понимал, что в header-файлах только для определения прототипов. Мне не была понятно, где реализуется сам код, в статических библиотеках, в DLL или где-то еще... Подскажите, тогда, если можно, еще вопрос: а для чего MS Visual C++ Runtime Library?

Comment: @SingleAsen как раз в случае шаблонов функционал в хедерах, а не спп-файлах

@Azat Galiev в рантайме вся стандартная библиотека, плюс реализации некоторых языковых конструкций